# Introductory offer does not appear for Sandbox testing

Tags: ios, swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit, storekit2

I currently have an introductory offer(with an auto-renewable subscription) with a trial period of 1 year set up and then $X.XX setup up after one year in up in App Store Connect, which is in the 'Ready to Submit' state. When testing with the StoreKit configuration testing for Xcode, the introductory offer appears correctly, and I can successfully make and cancel purchases. However, when testing on a device without the StoreKit configuration, using a new sandbox account, on device, the introductory offer does not appear, though the introductory price is visible for subscription and can make a purchase. The weird thing is `isEligibleForIntroOffer`  is showing true. Which means I should be seeing the introductory offer but just shows me the purcahse for $X.XX
Could you advise on how to ensure the introductory offer is displayed in this scenario?
Using Storekit 2

I tried using and creating various accounts, deleted the app, removed the subscription from sandbox. Is there something that I am missing here. It should be straight forward enough to see it.
Another weird part is I am unable to see Reset of subscription in the manage subscriptions screen.